# What is the standard method of finding satellite positions in between the 15 minute intervals in an SP3 file?

Tags: gps, interpolation, satellite, post-processing

SP3 files provide satellite positions for every 15 minutes. How would you find the satellite position at a time between two logged positions, i.e. 7 minutes after the last logged position?

I can think of several ways to do this:
1. Just use the position at the closest interval.
2. Linear interpolation between the intervals on either side.
3. passing a polynomial through several consecutive points and using the polynomial to estimate any satellite position within the time frame.

I don't think the overall effect on the accuracy of the estimates would vary much between all three of these (but I don't know this as a fact). Is this the case?
Is there a "standard" way for dealing with it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lagrangian polynomial are used for sure. I do not know if I would call it a standard. See for instance http://www.navipedia.net/index.php/Precise_GNSS_Satellite_Coordinates_Computation.